# undefined method `coordinates' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, undefined, null

I'm new to Rails and trying to figure out an issue with a Rails 2.3.14 site. The problem is this store locator i'm trying to fix keeps returning

> undefined method `coordinates' for nil:NilClass

when it can't find a store within the distance parameters. If it finds one then it works ok.

Here is the current code i'm trying to work with in my controller

```
  @map = GMap.new("locations-gmap-div", "locationsGMap")
  @map.control_init(:large_map => true, :map_type => true)
  @mapp.center_zoom_init(@locations.first.coordinates, 8)
```

This is what I tried to do with my code. I'm still very new to Rails so I apologize if i'm going way off field here.

```
 @map = GMap.new("locations-gmap-div", "locationsGMap")
 @map.control_init(:large_map => true, :map_type => true)

if @map.center_zoom_init(@locations.first.coordinates,8).nil?
    flash[:error] = 'Sorry, we could not find any stores matching that criteria.'  
    redirect_to store_locator_path          
else
    @map.center_zoom_init(@locations.first.coordinates,8)

end
```

Any help would be greatly appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its failing because the @locations are empty.

@locations will return []

@locations.first will return nil

nil.coordinates raises undefined method `coordinates' for nil:NilClass

```
if @locations.empty?
    flash[:error] = 'Sorry, we could not find any stores matching that criteria.'  
    redirect_to store_locator_path          
else
    @map = GMap.new("locations-gmap-div", "locationsGMap")
    @map.control_init(:large_map => true, :map_type => true)
    @map.center_zoom_init(@locations.first.coordinates,8)
end
```

Comment: When I tried this I get   Can only render or redirect once per action

Comment: I'm looking to see where else data is trying to be outputted to the screen.

Comment: Modified it. It makes sense to initilize the map in the else block since its not needed if the locations doesn't exist

Answer (score 1):

You haven't initialized `@locations.first`. The program seems to be trying to access the coordinates of something that doesn't exist (hence why the exception is on `nil:NilClass`).

Comment: I did in an earlier part of my code, I just didn't think it was necessary to show here. That's my mistake.